# Not getting response in ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Javascript code:

```
window.getTableContent = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/oeb_infos/" + $("#oeb_info_id").val() + "/show_toc.js",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(typeof data);
      if (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#toc.toc").html("<ul>");
        $.each(data, function(header) {
          var value;
          value = '';
          $.each(header.list, function(j) {
            return value = value + "<ul>";
          });
          value = value + ("<li><a href='#" + toc_part['id'] + "'>" + toc_part['value'] + "</a></li>");
          $.each(header['list'], function(j) {
            return value = value + "</ul>";
          });
          $("#toc.toc").append(value);
        });
        $("#toc.toc").append("</ul>");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

My rails code:

```
@info = OebInfo.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render js: @info.toc_book_json
  end
end
```

Not getting response in ajax success function. Getting empty object for done, complete, success, error.. But getting response in responseText. What is the problem? Can anyone help me on this to solve it.

Comment: Are you saying the success function does get called, but `data` is an empty object? Why are you calling `$.parseJSON(data)`? If you set `dataType:'json'` jQuery will parse the response automatically and pass the resulting object to your success handler (even if you don't set `dataType` jQuery _might_ try to parse the response if it thinks it is JSON due to the MIME type of the response).

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: can you console.log data and make sure that its coming back with nothing? if you're getting something in responsetext then it must not be undefined/null.. its probally an object.

Comment: alert(typeof data); itself not getting. Also not throwing any error in the console. But got response in responseText.I tried to put alert(data) and console.log(data). success function itself not getting called. Because its objects are empty.

Comment: How do you know the success function's "objects are empty" if it's not being called? How are you testing `responseText`? As an aside, what are you trying to do with those inner `$.each()` loops? It doesn't make sense to `return` a string, and also you're setting `value` to `'<ul><ul><ul><ul>'` (etc.), with one `<ul>` per item in `header.list` but nothing in between those tags.

Comment: I can correct my code only after getting into success function. I just written my functionality. But I cant able to check it.

Comment: What type of data does "/oeb_infos/" + $("#oeb_info_id").val() + "/show_toc.js" return? JSON? text?

Comment: What happens when you alert(data);

Comment: dataType is the problem. Now I tried with dataType:"text", now success function is getting called. Getting response in data. Thanks a lot for all your great support.

Comment: Just for future reference - you are specifying the data type as "text", then getting the text and converting it to Json.  You could just specify the data type as json in the first place, then you wouldn't need to convert it.  That's what @nnnnnn was saying.